# A serious bug using webView in ios7

Tags: objective-c

When i am opening a web view, memory is jump to 100M . if i ignore that for a moment, when closing the web view and removing all cache, memory is never get down to where it was, but only reduced by 10M . i have tried to start a new app,clean, i have checked it, and it still occurs.
You can't set a simple web view, because its memory will stay there forever .

clearing cache before remove the web view:

```
      [self.webView loadHTMLString: @"" baseURL: nil]; //tried with/without it


 [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:urlRequest];
 [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
 [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
 [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
  NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
  [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

 urlRequest=nil;

 for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies])
     if([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:[Globals sharedGlobals].currentLink])
         [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];

   [self.webView removeFromSuperview];
   [self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

loading the url :

```
  NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[Globals sharedGlobals].currentLink];
     urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
    [self.webView setDelegate:self];
    self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Try to reproduce it, and you will get the same. memory goes up and not goes down.

Comment: There y'go. Your question seems sound enough, and I didn't think the downvote was fair. Not only that, but yours is a problem similar to one I'm currently trying to suss out. But people will vote the way they like, there's nothing you can do about it, and that's what makes participating in SO frustrating from time to time.

Comment: @trudyscousin , have you manage to solve that problem? i have spent 6 hours , read every piece of information . no results .

Comment: Not only the memory increase, but crashes too when an attempt is made to empty the cache. Yeah, I'm still working on mine...

Comment: its amazing that there is no solution to that on the net, nor someone who is facing the same problem. webView is such a basic thing . i will start a bounty to that question when i can

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, this is the intended behavior. When you add a `UIWebView` object to the view hierarchy for the first time, an entire WebKit stack is loaded into memory, which is what causes this spike you see. The WebKit stack will remain loaded in the memory, even if you remove the webview from the view hierarchy and never show it again. Since the webkit stack is so large, it is only loaded on demand.

Use `UIWebView` with care! It is very powerful, but it comes with a large baggage. If you only need the webview to display simple pages, perhaps [the new attributed string additions in iOS7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) can help you, by parsing the web page into an attributed string, which you can display in a text view.

Comment: I am facing the same problem,and your answer actually say that you cant use a webView. Saying "you have to use it with care" doesnt solve a huge problem , that DOES NOT enable me to use it because as you said- it loads too much memory that doesnt get freed . sending him to do some kind of scraping- is worse , and if you use iOS and you simply wants to show a webpage YOU CANT. you just cant let that leaks to stay in your system. so what is your REAL solution to use it ?

Comment: And by the way- show a webview in text field is not legal, since you are actually still content. you can read more about it regarding the Flipboard issue .

Comment: @user1994291 I cannot tell you how to code your app. Thousands of apps use webviews and they are fine. We use webviews in our app extensively, and everything is fine. But not every app needs webviews - that is all I meant in my "care" comment. Whether you can or cannot use it is something only you can answer.

Comment: but still, maybe i am missing something. if we are making so much efforts to reduce our app memory, and we manage to set it on 30M for the iPad, than, a user opens webView, and the memory consumption is going up to 100M, and stay like that even if you close the webView, you actually caused a memory leak, and when you add just a little bit to that 120M, the first generation iPads will no longer be able to carry the memory pressure. So, what am i missing here? how do you use a webView, where you memory consumption is leak ?

Comment: Our app is iOS6 and above currently, so first generation iPads are not supported. But once upon a time, we did support iOS5, and everything worked fine. We found one way to reduce webview memory use was to load an empty page, but that had a limited applicability.

Comment: So you say that our app will not be able to work on iPad2 ? or any iPad with a 512M ? i must say even when i am using the iPad air, with an empty clear project, you just have to open the webView for a few times, and the system is crashing. I just cant seems to understand, how such a basic thing just does not perform well, and seems like nobody is making noise of it. Now ,we cant use a webView, which cause us a really big mess.

Comment: Our app works just fine on iPad2, iPhone 4, iPod 4, etc.

Comment: But how? try that: open a new project, set a webview, open and close it a few times, and boom- memory warnings. What is your memory consumption anyway when you open it?

Comment: Our app sits 40-80 MB use. When we load large amounts of data, we may reach 100 MB during ramp up, but then it goes down.

Comment: When you close the webView, as you already said, it should stay on 100M, because all of the webkits stuff. so how it goes down? (sorry for all the questions, but it seems that there is a serious leak and it somehow dont disturbs you)

Comment: I have just tried it again, opening a webView memory goes up to 80 and i get memory warning. i shouldnt get a memory warning for not violating any programing rule.

Comment: 100 MB is a little bit overblown. We see increase of 20 MB when webkit is loaded into memory. 20 MB that we will never see until the user kills the app and runs it again - until he opens a view with a webview in it. ~20MB is not something to get excited about.

Comment: Strange. this is not the case for me , and for others as you can read here.